# How to get selected spinner value during an update call?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a list where I enter data and also select a value from the spinner. Suppose I want to select a different value from the spinner, how to show the previously selected value first in the spinner before I select the new value?

This is the value that I initially selected

[image]

Before I select a new value the spinner should contain my previously selected value.

[image]

Comment: What you have tried ? use `OnItemSelectedListener ` for getting selected to show Selected item in TextView

Comment: I really can't tell what you're asking here, @Chandan.  Please be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

```
edt_dress_code.getSelectedItem().toString()
get selected item value
```

Answer (score 0):

See this sample code:-

In MainActivity.xml

```
 <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In MainActivity.Java

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter;
```

Initiallizing spinner items in adapter

```
final List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add("Select an item");
        items.add("Item1");
        items.add("Item2");
        items.add("Item3");
        items.add("Item4");
        items.add("Item5");

        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter); 

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                try {
                    if (position > 0) {

                        if (position == spinnerArrayAdapter.getPosition("Item5")) {
                            String previousSelectedITem = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
                            items.clear();
                            spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            items.add("Select an item");
                            items.add("Item1");
                            items.add("Item3");
                            items.add("Item5");
                            items.add("Item7");
                            items.add("Item9");
                            spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            spinner.setSelection(spinnerArrayAdapter.getPosition(previousSelectedITem));
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }

        });
```

In my case while selecting "Item5", I am updating the spinner items, and selecting the previous selected value.